# Site makes web browser suddenly stop and turn off in some IE browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

the site link is http://www.kosfan.com (korean site)

in some web browser (IE 7 and 8), the site suddenly stop and turn off in not only main pages but also other pages.

i have tried to find the reason why it happens, but i cannot.

i thought that possible reasons are javascript error, onload(ready) function and ajax-load  something like that.

is there any one who can solve this problem? help me!

thanks :)

Comment: What does "stop and turn off" mean? As in the web browser closes completely? Or...?

Comment: If the browser shuts down it's likely a bug in the browser. I don't remember if Flash is already sandboxed in IE7&8 so it can also be a problem with the Flash player. Try to disable Flash and visit the site. On Chrome worked flawlessly.

Comment: stop and turn off means "closes completely" with error message. It says ModName:mshtml.dll. and my site doesn't have any Flash. Actually i run this site and some users say that some IE7 and 8 are not available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had similar issues with IE and JQuery - it is definitely bug of the IE browser. You need to go debug the code and find where the crash happens. In my case it was a problem of accessing an element by id in JQuery way. When I replaced $("#id") for document.getElementById it stopped crashing :-)